# getting error in springboot mongo when updating with an image everything seems fine

Tags: mongodb, image, spring-boot, insert

When submiting data to my service, I'm getting the following error:

Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'entity' is not present] error and dont know what im missing any suggestion would help

Dont know what is the problem using similar api

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/entity")
public class EntityController {

    @Autowired
    IEntityRepository entityRepository;
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEntity", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
        public ResponseEntity<Entity> updateEntity(@RequestPart("entity") @Valid Entity entity, @RequestPart("file") @Valid Optional<MultipartFile> image) throws IOException {
    
    // routine to update a entity including image
            byte[] imageData = null;
            if (image.isPresent() && image.get() != null)
                imageData = image.get().getBytes();
            if (imageData == null && entity.getId() != null) {
                Optional<Entity> readEntity = entityRepository.findById(entity.getId());
                if (readEntity.get() != null)
                    imageData = readEntity.get().getImage().getData();
            }
            if (imageData != null) {
                entity.setImage(new Binary(BsonBinarySubType.BINARY, imageData));
            }
            Entity result = entityRepository.save(entity);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
    
        }

Models (did not add constructor or getters and setters)
public class Entity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Types types;
    private String username;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Binary image;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String contactNo;
    private String country;
    private Status status;
    private List<UserRolls> userRolls;
    private MemberShip memberShip;
    private Staff staff;

    private Payee payee;

    private List<BankAccount> userBankAccount;
    private String loginCode;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

React snippet using values from formik and getting the binairy data from the image im selecting ,dont suspect it to be the image
    

    async function submitForm(values) {
/* routine to send the request to the server/*
            const formData = new FormData();
            var postData = values;
            formData.append(
                'bank',
                new Blob([JSON.stringify(postData)], {
                    type: 'application/json',
                })
            );
    
            if (imageData) {
                formData.append('file', imageData);
            }
    
            //Send Api request
            return Api(`auth/updateUser`, 'Post', formData);
        }
```

Comment: How are you sending the request?

Comment: There is something wrong with your request that you send. When you send it through postman, chrome or whatever platform you are not adding image to the request via the correct format. We need to see how you are sending the request exactly.

Comment: can you elabarate i have my models and interface and the this post request or do you want to see the models

Comment: that is everything ,hope this is better @Bhagyesh

Comment: And im sending the request with react ,but I have a similar api and works fine when useing that one so I dont think the problem is in the frontend

Comment: @ChrisJnrPotgieter can you show your React code snippet? Thanks. Its like you coded it wrong, I had these kind of issues in the past and they lead to frontend code errors.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-shannon-zgl0p?file=/src/App.js:21486-28197

Comment: added to sandbox it is alot of code but formik and tabs dont work I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the frontend had an spelling error where I submit and append bank should have changed to entity